# Specify logit function explicitly in WinBUGS/OpenBUGS

Tags: bayesian, winbugs, r2winbugs, openbugs

I'm new to OpenBUGS and I got some problem in fitting a model with the logit() function.

Reading around I found that one possible solution for this would be explicit specify the logit function without using the WinBUGS’ own logit function:

> In more complex models, we have fairly often experienced problems when
>   using WinBUGS’ own logit function, for instance with achieving
>   convergence (actually, problems may arise even with fairly simple
>   models.). Therefore,it is often better to specify that transformation
>   explicitly by logit.p[i] <- log(p[i] / (1 – p[i])), p[i] <-
>   exp(logit.p[i]) / (1 + exp(logit.p[i])) or p[i] <- 1 / (1 + exp(-
>   logit.p[i])).

(more information here http://www.mbr-pwrc.usgs.gov/software/kerybook/AppendixA_list_of_WinBUGS_tricks.pdf at point 14.).

The problem is that I don't understand how to do that, let's suppose that my original likelihood function, using the WinBUGS integrated logit function, was:

```
for (i in 1:n){
    y[i] ~ dbern(p[i])
    logit(p[i]) <- beta[1] + beta[2]*x1[i] + beta[3]*x2[i] + beta[4]*x3[i] 
    }
```

How I explicit write that?

Thank you very much.

Vincenzo

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a colleague, I found the way to explicitly specify a logit function in OpenBUGS, the working code is the following:

```
for (i in 1:n){
y[i] ~ dbern(logit.p[i])
logit.p[i] <- 1 / (1 + exp(-p[i]))
p[i] <-  beta[1] + beta[2]*x1[i] + beta[3]*x2[i] + beta[4]*x3[i] 
}
```